# Spark - Remote Akka Client Disassociated

Tags: mapreduce, apache-spark

I am setting up Spark 0.9 on AWS and am finding that when launching the interactive Pyspark shell, my executors / remote workers are first being registered:

```
14/07/08 22:48:05 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Registered executor:
Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@ip-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.ec2.internal:54110/user/
Executor#-862786598] with ID 0
```

and then disassociated almost immediately, before I have the chance to run anything:

```
14/07/08 22:48:05 INFO cluster.SparkDeploySchedulerBackend: Executor 0 disconnected, 
so removing it
14/07/08 22:48:05 ERROR scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost an executor 0 (already 
removed): remote Akka client disassociated
```

Any idea what might be wrong? I've tried adjusting the JVM options spark.akka.frameSize and spark.akka.timeout, but I'm pretty sure this is not the issue since (1) I'm not running anything to begin with, and (2) my executors are disconnecting a few seconds after startup, which is well within the default 100s timeout.

Thanks!

Jack

Comment: Where do you launch the shell? Try launching it on the master node inside AWS, to make sure it's not a network setup issue. Also try `bin/spark-shell` to eliminate Python as a cause.

Comment: Already am doing the first, and the Scala shell returns the same error.

Comment: Is there perhaps a clue in the worker or executor logs? Or on `http://<machine>:4040/executors/`? (Yeah, basically I have no idea. Sorry!)

Comment: Just wanted to include more details: I'm building it from source but I've discovered that interestingly enough, using the `spark-ec2` scripts provided by Spark yields the same error in the worker logs. However, it doesn't kill the application...

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem, if not the same.
It started to work for me once the workers were connecting to master by using the very same name as the master thought it had.

My log messages were something like:

`ERROR remote.EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkWorker@idc1-hrm1.heylinux.com:7078] -> [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@vagrant-centos64.vagrantup.com:7077]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@vagrant-centos64.vagrantup.com:7077]].`


`ERROR remote.EndpointWriter: AssociationError [akka.tcp://sparkWorker@192.168.121.127:7078] -> [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@idc1-hrm1.heylinux.com:7077]: Error [Association failed with [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@idc1-hrm1.heylinux.com:7077]]`

`WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, idc1-hrm1 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.121.187 instead (on interface eth0)`

So check the log of the master and see what name it thinks it has.
Then use that very same name on the workers.